# Absolute child not scrollable

Tags: html, css

Basically I'm trying to make the chat messages scrollable. However as of right now the content doesn't seem to be scrollable. When the "chat-messages-wrapper" class was relative it'd scroll just fine however I want the chat messages to appear at the bottom initially which is why I switched it to absolute.

Html:

```
<div class="chat-widget">
   <div class="header">Social Chat</div>
   <div class="chat-messages-wrapper">
      <div class="chat-message">
         <img class="profile-image" src="../Content/images/facebook-profile.png" /> <span class="header-1">
         <img class="logo" src="../Content/images/facebook-logo.png" />
         <span class="username">Jens Olsen says:</span>
         </span> <span class="header-2">
         <button class="reply btn btn-primary btn-xs">Reply</button>
         <button class="like btn btn-success btn-xs">Like</button>
         <button class="spam btn btn-danger btn-xs">Spam</button>
         <span class="date">5:03PM</span>
         </span>
         <div class="text">This is the chat message. This is the chat message.</div>
      </div>
      <div class="chat-message">
         <img class="profile-image" src="../Content/images/facebook-profile.png" /> <span class="header-1">
         <img class="logo" src="../Content/images/twitter-logo.png" />
         <span class="username">Jens Olsen says:</span>
         </span> <span class="header-2">
         <button class="reply btn btn-primary btn-xs">Reply</button>
         <button class="like btn btn-success btn-xs">Like</button>
         <button class="spam btn btn-danger btn-xs">Spam</button>
         <span class="date">5:03PM</span>
         </span>
         <div class="text">This is the chat message. This is the chat message.</div>
      </div>
      <div class="chat-message">
         <img class="profile-image" src="../Content/images/default-avatar.png" /> <span class="header-1">
         <span class="username">Jens Olsen says:</span>
         </span> <span class="header-2">
         <button class="reply btn btn-primary btn-xs">Reply</button>
         <button class="like btn btn-success btn-xs">Like</button>
         <button class="spam btn btn-danger btn-xs">Spam</button>
         <span class="date">5:03PM</span>
         </span>
         <div class="text">This is the chat message. This is the chat message.</div>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="reply-box">
      <input class="reply-text" placeholder="Type your message here..." />
      <button class="btn btn-primary reply-button">Send</button>
   </div>
</div>
```

Css:

```
.chat-widget {
    position: fixed;
    right: 5px;
    bottom: 5px;
    height: 95%;
    width: 300px;
    background-color: #FFF;
    border: solid 3px #3B5998;
    overflow: hidden;
}

    .chat-widget .header {
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 18px;
        color: #FFF;
        background-color: #3B5998;
        font-weight: bold;
        padding-top: 5px;
        padding-bottom: 5px;
    }

.header {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 2;
    width: 100%;
}

.chat-messages-wrapper {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 40px;
    padding-left: 7px;
    padding-right: 7px;
    height: auto;
    overflow-y: auto;
}

.chat-message {
    padding-top: 5px;
    position: relative;
    border-bottom: solid 1px #000;
    overflow-y: auto;
}

    .chat-message .profile-image {
        height: 48px;
        width: 48px;
        border: solid 1px #000;
        margin-right: 5px;
    }

    .chat-message > .header-1 {
        position: absolute;
        height: 20px;
    }

        .chat-message > .header-1 .logo {
            width: 75px;
            height: 20px;
        }

        .chat-message > .header-1 .username {
            font-weight: bold;
        }

    .chat-message > .header-2 {
        position: absolute;
        top: 30px;
        height: 20px;
    }

        .chat-message > .header-2 > .reply {
            width: 50px;
        }

        .chat-message > .header-2 > .like {
            width: 50px;
        }

        .chat-message > .header-2 > .spam {
            width: 50px;
        }

        .chat-message > .header-2 .date {
            font-style: italic;
            position: relative;
            right: 0px;
        }

    .chat-message .text {
        position: relative;
        margin: 5px;
    }

    .chat-message:last-child {
        border-bottom: 0px;
    }

.reply-box {
    overflow-y: auto;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 5px;
}

    .reply-box .reply-text {
        width: 70%;
        height: 32px;
    }

    .reply-box .reply-button {
        width: 25%;
    }
```

Here's a JSFiddle with the entire code:
http://jsfiddle.net/5GCE5/1/

Comment: When you position something absolutely, it won't move, because it is removed from the document flow. If I'm not mistaken (I could be), this includes scrolling. In which case you'd need to use JavaScript or at least CSS transforms to move an absolutely-positioned element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to get [`overflow-y`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow-y) to work, you need to specify an explicit (min/max) `height` for the `.chat-messages-wrapper` element.

However, since the box is positioned absolutely, you could play with `top` and `bottom` properties to achieve the same effect:

**[Example Here](http://jsfiddle.net/5GCE5/10/)**

```css
.chat-messages-wrapper {
    position: absolute;
    padding-left: 7px;
    padding-right: 7px;
    /* height: auto; */
    bottom: 40px; /* = height of bottom element */
    top: 32px;    /* = height of top element    */
    overflow-y: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to give `.chat-messages-wrapper` a `max-height`

http://jsfiddle.net/5GCE5/6/